# Flashing stock Android 10 ROM in Samsung Galaxy M21

Tags: rom-flashing, stock-android, samsung-galaxy-m21

I want to flash a stock Android 10 ROM to my Samsung Galaxy M21 smartphone. I have some questions regarding the flashing process which I would like to know the answer to before I proceed:

- Will the stock ROM be able to detect the hardware features properly?
- Will it support the multi-camera setup of the phone?
- Will it support the Camera2 API?
- Will it support RAW photography?
- Will it have root access?
- Will it run well on the Exynos 9611 chipset?

Also, please tell me any other things which I need to consider.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but stock Android ROM means the original ROM that is installed by the manufacturer. So in this case, it's the one by Samsung, and should support original features on the phone. Unless you actually meant AOSP-based custom ROM?

Comment: Oh, is it that? Actually I mean to use the **_original Android ROM_** without any modification from any vendor. So, is there any custom ROM which can fit my above-mentioned needs?

Comment: The AOSP is considered [tag:vanilla-android] instead, i.e. pure Android without vendor customization. That said, there are probably many custom ROMs for Samsung Galaxy M21 and I don't know anything about them. Also, depending on the developers/maintainers, each ROM may also have different features (and bugs, usually labelled with "unofficial ROM"), so I'm afraid that as of current writing, this question is actually too broad to be answered and off-topic for finding custom ROM. You can try https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152 which usually refers XDA Forums for resources.